# Powerbi Matrix issues with the value field

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a problem with Powerbi I can't seem to fix. If the answer is obvious i am sorry but i am just starting out with Powerbi.

We are trying to make a dashboard that will show if a coworker is available or not based on a code 1 -3).

We check their availability per ISOWeek. If they don't have work that week they get code 1, when they have work code 2 etc.

These codes show up the right way in SQL but when I want to add them in my matrix table and have the coworker names on the rows, the ISOWeek on the columns and then when i add the Code in values Powerbi wants to show the total, total(distinct), first or last.

The problem is it wont use the code it got per isoweek. Is there a solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

[image: The structure of the table]

What is should look like in the matrix:
[image: Matrix table]

[image: Matrix in PowerBi]

Fixed it by giving the columns: don't Summarize on the modeling tab. Then I gave the code column the minimum value for each week.

Comment: the structure images are not showing in the question.

Comment: If i understand correctly i cant show images because i am new. You cant see the imgur links?

Comment: cool, I'm seeing them now. can you show a picture of the matrix and what it's doing in power bi?

Comment: Added a screenshot, as you can see it only gives either all 1's or 2's. I tried all the options but neither of them "eerste", "laatste", Aantal(unique) give the right values i want. its using all the data to give 1 answer but i need it to check the answer per week instead of for all.

Comment: what is the datatype on the codes? It looks like it's 'text'. Maybe you could make it a whole number and then use the sum. see if that helps.

Comment: I changed it to whole number and used sum. Now it gets the sum of every code value of the year 2022 for example 61 and then adds 61 in every week per coworker.

Comment: I have a meeting now - will be back soon - can help later if you haven't figured it out. You're close. Maybe try 'don't summarize' if that's an option on the code.

Comment: I think its fixed now! Thank you very much Zach! You helped me alot with this!

Comment: you're welcome phpnoob. Please share your solution for future visitors.